# How to change "My Site is scheduled for deletion.. " message Format in SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, my-site

When user is Diable/Deleted from AD. Their Manger get the below Message :

***Subject: The My Site of [user] is scheduled for deletion***

*The My Site of [user] is scheduled for deletion. As their manager you are now the temporary owner of their site. This temporary ownership gives you access to the site to copy any business-related information you might need. To access the site use this URL: http://users/personal/[user]*

is it possible to add a few more words that says "it will be deleted after 30 Days" to this Message.

Please can some insider tell me where this Message is actually located in SharePoint and How to Modify it.

It is MOSS 2007 SP2 64-bit environment. 3-WFE 1-APP 1 DB server.

Answer (score 1):

Actually don't think so, neither STSADM nor Powershell (to my knowledge) enable that kind of detail. It must be part of the TimerJob definition. You could however customize the process, but it would require VS 2010 development. SharePoint 2010 SDK has an example available here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12323